# How to get value from java code in java script array

Tags: java, javascript, html

I have a java code which i made by using MyEclipse.
In the main method I have an output which is an array [10,23,31,45].
My Question is how can i get these values in java script array.
Is there any ways or tools through which i can use my java object values in java script to display something in HTML.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: It's a little bit like asking if you can get a slice of apple from a banana ?

Comment: Java runs on a server, JavaScript runs on a client, so you would need to inject it from the server via HTTP. I am not familiar with Java but I'm sure they provide some method for this.

Comment: Is it a web app ? Do you want to output the java object values to a <script></script> inside JSP or related page ?

Comment: What context is your java code in? Console app? Applet? Servlet? You could put your java code in a servlet and then call it with ajax to get results back to the client

Comment: @jbabey - Java runs on Android, servers, virtual machines, just about anywhere. Who knows where this runs ?

Comment: Hi Dave thanks for the reply I'm getting output on java console I have done this coding through Hibernate. Is it possible to get the values in html through java script if i convert the output in XML.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that depends on how you create your html pages or generally get data onto your page. In most frameworks you could render the array directly into the hmtl source which is delivered to the browser.

In a JSP it might be something like this:

```
<script ...>
  var myarray = <%=Arrays.toString(javaArray)%> <!-- not sure about the formatting though, might have to be altered-->
</srcipt>
```

*Edit*

To clarify: what you need is a string representation of your array that fits JavaScript, and `toString()` might not result in what you need. In that case you could either use a JSON library to convert your objects to JSON (and thus a JavaScript compatible represenation) or write your own array/object -> string converter.

Using the above code with `int[] javaArray = {1,2,3};` would result in 
`var myarray = [1, 2, 3];`

Comment: You will either need to convert you Java file into a servlet and include it in some way into your JSP page, or, if the contents of your main method does not rely on anything outside of the main method, just copy and paste the main method contents into the JSP page between <% %> tags.

Comment: @cmcculloh sorry, but I don't get your comment. ;)

Comment: It was more or less just expanding upon your answer. You didn't say anything that I thought was incorrect, I just wanted to clarify for the asker that they couldn't just take their POJO and expect it to magically populate the javaArray in your answer.

Comment: @cmcculloh I see :) Yet, the comment is hard to understand, especially, since you don't have to convert a Java class to a servlet. You can just use your POJO as long as there is a correct String representation that fits JavaScript. There's no need for Servlets or main methods :)

Comment: Sure, but, they specifically mention that they have a "main method". I was assuming they were referring to the typical "main" method in a POJO. I may have been taking them too literally. Maybe they were just saying the "primary" method in their file...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute javascript from within java in the JVM , this might be of help : http://commons.apache.org/bsf/

If you want to output java object values in JSP , you can use EL , scriptlets , expressions etc .

**Expression:** `var javascriptArray = <%= javaArray.toString() %>`

**EL:** `var javascriptArray = ${javaArray}` (mind the formatting in this case)

**JSTL:** `var javascriptArray = [

  <c:forEach var="element" items="${javaArray}" varStatus="cursor">

    "${element}"

    <c:if test="${!cursor.last}">,</c:if>

  </c:forEach>

]`